# How to acummulate data in JSON?

Tags: java, json

I extract some data from a database and I want to create a JSON based on this data. The JSON must look like this:

```
Ducument1:  {
               documentDescription: "some description1"
               idTask: 49
               idDocument: 1
               documentFilepath: "D:\workspace\docs"
             }
Ducument2:  {
               documentDescription: "some description2"
               idTask: 49
               idDocument: 2
               documentFilepath: "D:\workspace\"
             }
```

I tried several things, but they didn`t work. Such as:

```
 public JSONObject get(){
    TaskDocumentEntity document = new TaskDocumentEntity();

    JSONObject childJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arrayJson = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject parentJson = new JSONObject();

    for(int i=0;i <  taskDocumentRepository.getCountDocs();i++){



        jo.put("idTask",taskDocumentRepository.getAllDocumentsByIdTask().get(i).getIdTask());
        jo.put("documentDescription",taskDocumentRepository.getAllDocumentsByIdTask().get(i).getDescriere());
        jo.put("documentFilepath",taskDocumentRepository.getAllDocumentsByIdTask().get(i).getFilepath());

        ja.add(jo);
        mainObj.put(i,ja);
    }
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON: It's missing a number of quotes and commas, and a few things need escaped.

Comment: Moreover, your question is missing a few things, such as expected and actual behaviour, errors or an actual question.

Comment: Yeah, that comment is for real. I'd have made the same comment if @Biffen hadn't beat me to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm for real. If that's the "JSON" you're expecting, then who knows where things went wrong, especially since you haven't told us.

Comment: You might want to read about "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", and about "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Answer (score 1):

since you don't tell us what doesn't work, so I just assume things:

it is most likely the problem is having your `JsonObject` and `Jsonarrays` in wrong places relative to your loop.

try this:

```
JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i <  taskDocumentRepository.getCountDocs();i++){
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject mainObj=new JSONObject();


    jo.put("idTask",taskDocumentRepository.getAllDocumentsByIdTask().get(i).getIdTask());
    jo.put("documentDescription",taskDocumentRepository.getAllDocumentsByIdTask().get(i).getDescriere());
    jo.put("documentFilepath",taskDocumentRepository.getAllDocumentsByIdTask().get(i).getFilepath());

    mainObj.put(i,jo);
    ja.add(mainObj);

}
```

**NOTE:**

where I initiated `jo` and `ja` and `mainObj` also I put mainObj outis

Answer (score -2):

object creation wrong 
JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();

```
for(int i=0;i <  taskDocumentRepository.getCountDocs();i++){
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject mainObj=new JSONObject();
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer to include the relevant details of how this code works. Also please clean up your code blocks.